# Add Foreign Key to existing table in certain condition

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship

[image]

I was trying to alter to create foreign key relationship for SalesREP, but I am not sure how to deal with the correct syntax to make the first name PLUS last name associating with tables CustomerDetail and Users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all I know it can't be done with a foreign key in most database systems.

You can consider :

- developing a BEFORE INSERT trigger to check if an entry inserted in the second table corresponds to an entry in the first table. But 
  it is not a good choice if a large amount of data to be processed because the concatenation will take time
- improving the model, adding ID's to identifiy customers (then you'll can define a foreign key). Database system usually provide auto-increment functionnalities.